# Typescript Class where property names are unknown in advance

Tags: typescript

This is what I've tried

```
type SpecificType ={a:number; b:string};

type SomeInterface { 
  [key: string]: SpecificType
}  
class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {
  field1: {
   a: 1,
   b: ""  
 }
}
```

The problem is I get this error: `Index signature is missing in type 'SomeClass'`

It goes away if I put `[key:string]: SpecificType` in SomeClass, but I want to avoid that.

Also, TS doesn't recognize the type of fields in SomeClass.

Is there a solution for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually possible to do via [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).
Just name the interface same as class.

```
type SpecificType = {a:number; b:string};

interface SomeClass { 
  [key: string]: SpecificType
}
 
class SomeClass {
  field1 = {
   a: 1,
   b: ""  
 }
}
```

If you have multiple classes, then use it like this:

```
type SpecificType = {a:number; b:string};
type SomeInterface = {
  [key: string]: SpecificType
};

interface SomeClass extends SomeInterface { }
class SomeClass {
  field1 = {
   a: 1,
   b: ""  
 }
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAypDGBLAZo%20AVc0C8UDeAhgFwB2ArgLYBGEATgNxRVEDOwtiJA5gL70BQoSLAD2FCAEkSwOsgLwc%20flCgBtANYQQRKGw7cAujrgQkqDFn59%20-TjNpyFo8QGEANgRYsoEAB4ySABNvGDFJaVl5aDwoHmV%20eA8vZwh3T288ZShUCDdAgEYoXEyVKGIofIAaLKYdACI65TieIA)

Answer (score 3):

```
type SpecificType = { a: number; b: string };

abstract class SomeAbstractClass {
  [key: string]: SpecificType;

}
class SomeClass extends SomeAbstractClass {
  fields1 = {
    a: 1,
    b: "2"
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 cool, didn't know this would work. this actually looks even better (at least, cleaner) than the solution in my answer. the main difference is that it actually emits the `SomeAbstractClass` to js, but shouldn't be a big deal

Comment: TS still doesn't recognize the type of field1 with this approach

Answer (score 1):

You can use generic types to do what you want: however, this is under the condition that when implementing `SomeInterface` you already know what member(s) of the class should implement that interface. Otherwise it is a chicken-and-egg problem and your original approach will be the only solution.

```ts
type SpecificType = { a:number; b:string };

type SomeInterface<T extends string> = { 
  [key in T]: SpecificType
}

class SomeClass implements SomeInterface<'field1'> {
  field1 = {
    a: 1,
    b: ""
 }
}
```

See it on [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAypDGBLAZo%20AVc0C8UDeUAhgFwB2ArgLYBGEATgNxTXEDOwdipA5lAL4MAUINCRYAe0oQAkqWD1kheBAA86KBAAe80gBNWUdpx4A%20KLgKCoUANoBrCCChco6ALrFYCFGkyRBfMLwADaErAYwkhAAwqHhzpRgwRBSchFRsvJ0isoqAOSoEMG6AIx5ZnhWUIXFJeb4VdYkUCUANI3MngBEXVaBfEA).

Comment: How would the generic type <'field1'> work with multiple fields ?

Comment: @DusanJovanov Then use a union type `SomeInterface<'field1' | 'field2'>`